# Shortcut issue from google play store

Tags: android

When I download and install the app from google play store, a shortcut will be created on the home screen. The issue is, when I start the app and push it to the background, then, if I click the shortcut to resume the app, it is not call the background app, instead of start a new one.

If I want to resume the background app, how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [launchMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) attribute for your activity.

Using this you can force your app to have a single instance (using `singleInstance` or `singleTask`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the question is launchMode only for activity but not for application. My entry activity is splash activity.